# Why is this query failing on an empty line?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9` but line 9 has nothing on it and it shows that the error is an empty string in the message.

```
START TRANSACTION;DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `ReporteAcumulado`;


CREATE  DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `ReporteAcumulado`(in Tipo int,in dtInicio date,in dtFin date,in dtmensual date)

SQL SECURITY INVOKER

BEGIN

if Tipo=0 then


END if;


if Tipo=1 then


end if;

END

COMMIT;
```

[image: MySQL query failing on an empty line]

Comment: Don't post pics

Comment: @GursheeshSingh why not? I'm just showing it so it has the line numbers there and shows that it's an empty line

Comment: Your code is not failing because of a syntax error on line 9. It is likely an error on a previous line that eventually results in the SQL parser to fail on line 9. Therefore it would be handy to have the original code in text form as well. Currently is partially blocked by the dialogue box.

Comment: Just post your complete script, or first try to eliminate all lines that have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Can you run it SQL statement by SQL statement and find out which SQL statement is crashing?

Comment: I added basic code that has the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL is interpreting the semicolons between the BEGIN and END statements as terminating the CREATE PROCEDURE statement, rather than simply being part of the code of the procedure.

You should change the delimiter from `;` to something else (`//` is commonly used when defining MySQL procs). If you don't already have it, add `DELIMITER //` before the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, and put `DELIMITER ;` after the `END` statement for the procedure. I also don't believe that you need to start and commit a transaction when defining a procedure - I've never found it necessary, but perhaps you're doing something different. You also need `//` after the END. In addition, I've never seen an empty block between `IF...THEN...END IF` so I'm not sure how that might affect things.

So your code should look something like

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `ReporteAcumulado`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE  DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `ReporteAcumulado`(in Tipo int,in dtInicio date,in dtFin date,in dtmensual date)

SQL SECURITY INVOKER

BEGIN

if Tipo=0 then


END if;


if Tipo=1 then


end if;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

The [MySQL documentation for CREATE PROCEDURE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) explains it this way:

> The example uses the MySQL client delimiter command to change the statement delimiter from `;` to `//` while the procedure is being defined. This enables the `;` delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by MySQL itself.